# Database Relationships inquiry

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Need some guidance with relationship design. Scenario: User can have up to 4 cars at anytime, cars have their own properties(color, make, cost). Is it fair to say that there is a "many to many" relationship between user and car, and use a link table between them. Or is it a one user to many cars and just insert carID into user table?

Thanks

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tag.  (2) In general, 0-4 cars would be considered a 0-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-many is a situation where (in your world) a user can own several cars, but also a car can have many owners (users). Your case sounds like a one to many scenario.

The classic example of many to many is students-courses, where a student can enlist in many courses and each course has many students.

In your case, if each car has just 1 owner, this is a one to many case, and I would just add a `userId` column in the `cars` table. This would support unlimited, more than 4 cars per user.